# Determine the width of an iframe's parent container inside the iframe on mobile pbrowsers

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-browser, cross-domain

Our customers host their own HTML web pages, and we provide some of the content of those pages as embedded `iframe` elements. (Which means their content and our content have different domain origins.) They typically provide a `div` element that contains our `iframe` element. (Note that we have no control over their web page content, only over our `iframe` content.)

The `iframe` contains JavaScript code that determines the maximum size it can fill, which should be the dimensions of the outer `div`. This maximum width is used to control (show/hide) scrolling elements within the `iframe` content.

The problem is that on some **mobile browsers**, the contents of the `iframe` is not properly constrained (clipped) to the size/boundaries of its parent `<div>`. In other words, the dimensions of the `iframe` are larger (wider) than its parent `div`. (This is not a problem on desktop browsers.)

**So the question is**: How can the `iframe` code determine the true proper size of its parent element (especially cross-domain)? The best I can get, it seems, is the apparent size of the `iframe` itself and its children elements.

Adding `overflow:hidden` to the parent `div` properly hides/clips the iframe content that extends past the `div` bounds, but the `iframe` code still cannot determine what that dimension (width) actually is. (Again, this is apparently not a problem on desktop browsers.)

*Note:* Similar questions (e.g., [Detect the width of an iframe from within the iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36079342/detect-the-width-of-an-iframe-from-within-the-iframe)) address the problem of accessing the dimensions of the `iframe` *itself* from within the `iframe`; I need to access the dimensions of the `iframe`'s parent container.

**SOLUTION**

I ended up placing the `iframe` element within its own `div` element, and accessing the width of that containing element. (There does not appear to be any way for the `iframe` to directly access its parent.)

Answer (score 0):

Your iframe page has to talk the other pages. [Here](https://github.com/batuhankok/auto-height-iframe) is the my example repo on Github, this is what I'am talking...

**EDİT:**

**Every outsource page:**

```
function windowWidth(){
    return document.getElementById('content').clientWidth;
}
```

**Iframe page:**

```
window.onload = function(){

    setInterval(function(){

      var iframeWidth = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.windowWidth();
      document.getElementById('iframe').style.width = iframeWidth + "px";

     }, 10);

}
```

Comment: I still don't see how the iframe can access the width of its parent element (especially across domains).

Comment: You should do that: your iframed page has to say its width (in my example by the function of windowWidth();) and then, you have to know its width from the variable of iframeWidth.